# NSDateFormatter not showing full month name, only single digit number

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Not sure what the issue is, but instead of getting a month name "July", I get "07".

```
dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];    
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, h:mm a"];
```

I have tried M, MM, MMM, MMMM, and all of them give me a number, instead of the month name, though with different amounts of leading 0s.

Comment: I think this line is the problem .. [dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]]; don't know what is your purpose to use `systemLocale` but you can try `currentLocale` instead of `systemLocale`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Turns out to be an issue with the second line, `setLocale`.  I assume that the system won't default to using english month names when the `locale` has been manually set?  I live in an english speaking `locale`, but maybe it doesn't matter.

In any case, not setting the locale fixes the month name issue.

```
dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];    
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, h:mm a"];
```

Answer (score 15):

The problem is the locale, not the format. Check this out:

http://waracle.net/mobile/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/

Basically, "MMMM" will give you the full name for the month.

Answer (score 8):

`-systemLocale` is not what you want here. It returns a fallback locale if no other locale fits. Use `-currentLocale` to get the user's current locale.

Also:
You should use `NSDateFormatter`'s `+dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:` method to get the correct date format. In some languages the day comes before the month, etc. and vice versa.